# stretch border to existing space

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this:

```
<Border Background="Gray">
   <TextBlock x:Name="Text" 
              Text="{Binding Name}" 
              Margin="0, 5" 
              FontSize="16"/>
</Border>
```

It looks like this: (There are three of those)

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

(Border stretching to end of the space + some control over the height of the border.)

### p.s. I do not have to use borders, anything that will achieve the same effect will do.

**update:** This is part of a DataTemplate for a ListBoxItem. It's defined in a style like this:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Text"
                       Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       Margin="0, 5" 
                       FontSize="16"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I tried to set the HorizontalAlignment to "Stretch" and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" (on a Border)

Comment: may you show more code?

Comment: Where do you place the border? In the ItemTemplate of ListBox?

Comment: just curious why not just set background for TextBox?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Because maybe I want more than just text in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found this as the easiest solution to accomplish exactly what I wanted:

- I create a grid (with one column and one row)
- I create a Rectangle inside (which automatically stretches to the grid space)
- I create a textBox (which automatically renders **on top** of the Rectangle)

Here's how it looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="..."/>
    <TextBox ... />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `StackPanel` will work if your `TextBlock` numbers are fixed:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="Text 1" Style="{StaticResource style1}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Text 2" Style="{StaticResource style1}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Text 3" Style="{StaticResource style1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Or if the `TextBlock` is generated base on some data source, use an `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Style="{StaticResource style1}"  Text="{Binding Name}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to use grid rows.
Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="text 1" Background="gray"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="text 2" Background="gray"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="text 3" Background="gray"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Why is that easier than using a StackPanel ?

Comment: Because a grid row will auto size to the window width, a stackpanel will not.

Comment: Try  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel> and you will see magic happen.

Comment: @Nawed Nabi Zada, yes you are right, in this simple case vertical stackpanel will also work. Its all personal preference. I tend to not use stackpanels because of the overrun in the orientation direction.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<Border Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
 <TextBlock x:Name="Text" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Text="{Binding Name}" 
          Margin="0, 5" 
          FontSize="16"/>
</Border>
```